# Iterating for loop Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is the problem: 
Write a program named q1() that prompts the user for the starting and ending distance in
Kilometers (km), and an increment value. It should then print the conversion table showing values for
Kilometers, Miles (M) and Feet (ft). Each value should be displayed as they are calculated.

this is my code:

```
 print("This program prints a translation table between the Kilometers (km), Miles (M) and Feet (ft) scales.")

start_km = input("Enter the Starting Kilometers (km): ")
start_km = int(start_km)
end_km = input("Enter Ending Kilometers (km): " )
end_km = int(end_km)
increment = input("Increment value: ")
increment = int(increment)
km = start_km
M = km*(.621371)
ft = M*(5280)

print("km", "   ", "M", "   ", "ft")
print("==========================")
list = ['km', 'M', 'ft']
for i in range(start_km,end_km+1,increment):
    km = start_km
    M = km*(.621371)
    ft = M*(5280)
    print( km, "    ", M, "    ", ft)
```

my problem is that i am getting a list but it is repeating the input value and not incrementing the calculation. how do i get it to iterate ?

Comment: You keep resetting `km` to `start_km` *inside* the loop, i.e. `km = start_km`. You need to increment it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(start_km,end_km+1,increment)
```

does not change the value of start_km, so you are just printing the same value again and again. The for loop changes the value of `i`, starting at start_km and ending at `end_km`, so you should do:

```
for km in range(start_km,end_km+1,increment):
    M = km*(.621371)
    ft = M*(5280)
    print( km, "    ", M, "    ", ft)
```

which increments `km` automatically, just like you wanted

Comment: this was super helpful and easy to understand. Thanks so much , really helped!!

Comment: @MinnaAdelRubio always glad to help

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
km = i
```

inside loop not,

```
km = start_km
```